# RHEL6: Failed Dependencies when installing a package

Tags: linux, rhel, linux-kernel, oracle-database

Hi I'm getting errors when forcing to install unixODBC package on RHEL 6 here is the following error: http://flic.kr/p/jBEFvP

I don't know where to get the following packages that were needed by the unixODBC package

Comment: why vote down? :S

Comment: probably because there are lots of answers to this question already that you would have found if you searched the site before posting. Also because you linked to a picture instead of copying the actual output as test.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use plain rpm(1) to install packages, it doesn't handle dependencies. The tool to be used is yum(1). This should be given in the instalation instructions, and in the basic system admnistration guide for RHEL.

*Do not* install packages that don't come from the official repositories for RHEL (perhaps adding [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL)) unless you are very, *very* clear of what you are doing, and why; and are willing the pay the (rather high) cost of keeping track of security fixes and new versions.